# C++ How to unmap unused global array from RAM?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, posix

In C++ when you declare a big array, say 500MB, it doesn't get mapped to RAM immediately because it is not used yet. As soon as I access a page from the array for the first time, it gets mapped to physical memory. Now the system knows that I am using that page, but how do I tell the system that I am not using some page anymore and that it can unmap it at its will?

In my case I just need to occasionally, so not all the time, fill a big array and operate on it with fast random access. Now I could use malloc every time, but why would I do that? There are ways to tell the system that you don't need some page, but they all both unmap it from physical space *and* virtual space. I just want to unmap it from physical space. Is it not possible?

Comment: *Now I could use malloc every time, but why would I do that?* Why indeed? This is C++! We have much better tools than `malloc`.

Comment: You might be interested in using `void * bigBuf = mmap(NULL, numBytes, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)` and (later on) `munmap(bigBuf, numBytes)` to get the behavior you want.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner After `munmap` the next use of the array would have to `mmap` again. That's the same as calling `malloc`/`new` and `free`/`delete` except more complex and less portable.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think the difference is that with `munmap()` the process would release the memory to the OS, whereas with `free()` the memory would likely remain in the process's local-memory pool for later reuse inside the process.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner `malloc` on Linux and BSD systems will use `mmap` for allocations above a certain size and `free` then will `munmap` the block. Only small allocations use `sbrk` and local memory pools for reuse.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special.

Memory management units automatically move virtual memory pages in and out of physical RAM as needed. If a page hasn't been used in a while, and its memory is needed for something else, it will be paged out. Physical RAM holds the pages that have been used most recently, older pages are just evicted if they're backed by a file (e.g. the text segment of programs), or they're written to the swap area of disk and then evicted.

When you're done with the entire array you should deallocate it with `delete[]`. Depending on the design of the memory allocator this may or may not remove the memory pages from your virtual memory, but you don't have any direct control over that.

If you're talking about a static array, there's no way to indicate that you're done with it. If you need to do that, the array must be allocated dynamically with `new` so you can `delete` it.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Actually, I don't want it to hang anywhere, it's not backed by a file and I don't want the pages to be swapped to the disk. When I stopped "touching" the page, the system still doesn't know if I left some meaningful data in that page or not. I want to tell it exactly that. Pages are not in the heap, they are in some static space or whatever it is called...

Comment: The only way to tell the system that you're done with it is by deleting it. If you don't delete it, there's the possibility that you may use it later, so it can't remove it from virtual memory.

Comment: So there is no way to release pages of a global variable, right? Not even some system specific function? I feel like I saw some functions that do this for Windows

Comment: Not that I've ever heard of, but I don't do Windows.

Comment: Yeah... Me neither, I am on linux. However, "VirtualFree" is the Windows API function that might do what I need

Comment: The problem with using that is there may be other variables on the same memory page, and you'll free them as well. You would normally only use it if you allocated the memory explicitly using `VirtualAlloc()`

Comment: The equivalent on Unix would be to use `mmap()` to allocate a block of virtual memory. You can then use `munmap()` to release it.

Comment: Thank you! I just found the solution, it is indeed mmap(), I posted

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, luckily, I found another [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405883/can-an-application-explicitly-commit-and-decommit-memory), where it is exposed that using `mmap()` with `MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED` option to allocate the array and `madvise()` with `MADV_REMOVE` option does the trick. You can check the man-pages for details.

Comment: `MADV_FREE` might be better. It sounds like `MADV_REMOVE` will forcefully unmap the pages while `MADV_FREE` only marks the pages as disposable but will keep them mapped if there is no memory pressure. Given enough memory the next use of the big array will be faster with the pages still mapped.